# How do I make my electron app behave like a mobile device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, instagram, user-agent

For example, visiting instagram.com/direct/inbox/ gives a 404 error but when you turn on dev tools's "device toolbar" and select a mobile device, instagram shows me the DMs page.

I am trying to do this in a small electron app and I've already tried setting the user agent to an ipad/samsung one but instagram still detects its not a real device and still redirects me to the home page.

This is my code:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, session} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 850,
  })

  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {
    details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Mobile Safari/537.36';
    callback({ cancel: false, requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders });
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL('https://instagram.com/direct/inbox')

}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Read documentation `webContents` method https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents

Try, its worked me

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 412, height: 732, title: 'Instagram Desktop'})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.webContents.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko; googleweblight) Chrome/38.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19");
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://instagram.com/direct/inbox')
```

Founded from https://github.com/azishapidin/instagram-electron/blob/master/main.js

Comment: Just tried this and it still doesn't work. I think there is something more to it than just a user agent change. there is some validation done by the js locally because I can see the DM screen open for like a fraction of a second and then redirect me to the home page

Answer (score 0):

From [webContents](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents) instance, you can utilize this method:

> [webContents.enableDeviceEmulation(parameters)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsenabledeviceemulationparameters)

And this instance, for accesing and utilizing [Chrome DevTools Protocols](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/):

> [webContents.debugger](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/debugger)